# Is there a limit to the number of participants assigned to a collect feedback workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow, limitations

We have a business consultant that needs to run `"collect feedback"` workflow for ~16 users.

It seems there is a character limit in the first `Assign To` field.

Is there a limit to the number of participants `Assign To` a collect feedback workflow? If so, what is the limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Assign To` field is considered a `People and Group` field, and Unfortunately, Microsoft didn't mention exactly what's the limit of users per `People and Group` field. it just mentioned the `size per column` that is **10 bytes**, where the sum of all columns in a SharePoint list cannot exceed **8,000 bytes**

For more details check S[oftware boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013 - Column](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Column)

---

Regarding your scenario, I tried to add more than 16 users in `Assign To` field on my side that worked properly, (`By the way, you can Everyone in this field!`)

**But It is recommended** to create a group and add these users to it, and at  `Assign To` field, set this group instead of adding 16 users one by one.

Comment: Thanks @M.Qassas ...we created a reviewer group and it looks to work as expected.

Comment: @JuanVillegas Glad to hear it's worked, Please don't forget to Mark the answer as accepted :)